# Change characters in a string by slicing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, slice

I have a little question. Can i in javascript use string.slice() = x?

Example: "Hello world!".slice(2,3) --> = x <-- can I use this?

```
                           ^ the 3rd character in the string
```

So, can i change characters with a slice? (:

Comment: What is your input and expected output??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not assign a value to a part of a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type):

> Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string.

You can split the string into an array of characters, change the wanted character at the given index and join the array for a new string.

```js
var string = "Hello world!",
    array = string.split('');
    
array[2] = 'X';

string = array.join('');

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to get the character.

```
 var x = "Hello world!".slice(2,3);
 console.log(x);
```

However, you can't change character with a slice. See [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375615/4154250) how to do that.